# Multipart send using c# connection problems

Tags: c#, multipartform-data

I'm trying to implement the sending to a webservice a multipart/form  using this code on c# in this [link](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c).

I have to add in the "private static HttpWebResponse PostForm" the next:

1- To avoid the problems of proxy in my company:

```
request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; ;
request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

2- To allow gzip and deflate.

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

3- To allow connection keepalive:

```
request.KeepAlive = true;
```

And/Or (I tried both and each one by separated)

But I'm having trouble with the

```
return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

In the method "private static HttpWebResponse PostForm" because it throws me the exception:

> ```
> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
> ```

**What I tried:**

```
request.Timeout = 10000;
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 10000;
```

Commenting the

```
request.userAgent
```

part.

Really I don't know what else to do. Please help